# ng-if evaluated in two steps and UI is blinking

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have a table built with ng-repeat.
In table cell I need to show a link or dropdown when user click on link.
So I declared my html like this (JADE template):

```
tr(ng-repeat='table in importMeta.displayedTables track by $index')
    td
        a(ng-if='!table.editCache' ng-click='startEditDbTableCache(table)') {{dbTableCache(table)}}
        button(ng-if='table.editCache' bs-select ng-model='table.cache' bs-options='item.value as item.label for item in importCaches')
```

And in my controller I switch table edit/view state in function:

```
....
$scope.curDbTable = null;

$scope.startEditDbTableCache = function (tbl) {
        if ($scope.curDbTable) {
            $scope.curDbTable.editCache = false;
            $scope.curDbTable.editTemplate = false;
        }

        tbl.editCache = true;
        $scope.curDbTable = tbl;
    };
```

But UI is blinking because of it seems like ng-if evaluated two times, and at some point for short period of time I see two controls in table cell.

It is possible to make AngularJS to evaluate both ng-if at once?

Or may be I could show dropdown with some other technique?
I use ng-if because I could have a lot of rows in table and dropdown could have a lot of items, that's why I need ng-if instead of ng-show.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that problem not in AngularJS, but in CSS animation makes UI blinking.
After some CSS tweaks - blinking is gone.